# RegEx design a pattern to extract id from url?

Tags: regex

www.example.com/companies/23/brands/39/properties/78

how do i match the properties id(78) with regex from the url

as my try this pattern.

```
(\/properties\/)([0-9]+)\/?

Match 1
Full match  46-60   `/properties/78`
Group 1.    46-58   `/properties/`
Group 2.    58
```

that match in group2 it's ok. 
but actually i want to match only the digit after `/properties/` only !

How do i design a pattern to match this?

Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the match in group 1 no problem, in your example you're capturing it which you don't need to do.

/properties/([\d]+)/?

should give you group 1 matching the number.

Comment: [link](https://regex101.com/r/cU5lC2/857)


`
Match 1
Full match 46-60 /properties/78
Group 1. 58-60 78
`
Thank. 


but it still not work as my expected.

there have a way to capture the digit as a Full match ?

Comment: The full match is what your regex describes,  so in this case the property and the digit. the parentheses indicate a capture group. Which is why group 1 is the number.  Why is it that you want the number to be the full match?

Comment: If you need to extract the id you can use match.group (1)

Comment: i don't known more about regex pattern. just try to ask for the better way if it possible to do.

your answer's OK..
Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Add '$' to end of your regex. '$' matches end of string.